# What's the Rust way of asserting on the return value of a function that has side effects?

Tags: debugging, rust, assert

In C, asserts can disappear by defining `NDEBUG`, so we tend to write things like:

```c
const bool ok = my_function();
assert(ok);
```

However, it looks like asserts in Rust are always present in every type of build regardless of configuration, so what's considered better:

```
let ok = my_function();
assert!(ok);
```

Or:

```
assert!(my_function());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> it looks like asserts in Rust are always present in every type of build

Yes, [`assert!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.assert.html) is always there, but [`debug_assert!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.debug_assert.html) is only enabled in debug builds.

---

> what's considered better

This is opinion-based. Do whatever makes you happy. I've personally been bitten by putting side-effecting code in code that disappeared due to conditional compilation more times than I want, so I'd favor making the assertion a separate line. However, this will lead to unused variable warnings when the assert is compiled away.

Even better, re-evaluate *why* you have side-effects in an assert; I'd wager it's almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Which is more common? Rust seems to dictate a lot of style decisions, I'm surprised that this isn't one of them.

Comment: @user1000039 neither way of asserting on a side-effecting function is **common** because asserting on a side-effecting function is *just a bad idea*. There's no reason to have idioms for code that we shouldn't be writing in the first place. When it comes to asserting on a non-side-effecting function, I'd expect that `assert!(some_boolean())` would be more common because it's shorter.

Comment: The Rust idiom for a possibly-failing function is to return `Result<(), SomeError>`, not `bool`. So if you want to panic if the function fails, you wouldn't `assert!` on it, you would `.unwrap()` the result.

Comment: Why not a variable with a leading underscore: `let _ok = ...; assert!(_ok);`, this should silence the warnings.

Comment: @MatthieuM. but in half of the compilations you *are* using the variable. Sure, there are lots of ways to silence this warning, but my point is more along the lines of "think about why you have a warning in the first place".